# How to customize ".NET FrameworkInitialization Error"?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application with when new user execute it on there machine they will get this ugly error message :

> To run this application, you first must install on of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework: v4.0.30319

I need to customize this message to a better GUI and maybe in different languages,
how could I do that ?

Comment: A better idea is to package that .NET framework version with your application and distribute it together. An error is still an error, no matter how nicely it's displayed.

Comment: I know it might seem odd, but I'm on some limits, therefore can not pack it with the distribute stuff.

Comment: Have your installer download the framework from Microsoft during the install process.

Comment: I can not use any installers, I do not want to force user in install .NET 4, the point is that I just want to warn them with a better UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to 'customize' that dialog is going to be to build a native (non .NET) wrapper or stub for your application which checks whether the .NET framework is installed. You can do this via the registry (support.microsoft.com/kb/315291), and display a message if not.

You could do all this, or take the common sense approach of automatically installing the framework when necessary via bundling or direct download as Mark Hall commented.

**Update describing simple wrapper process**

1. Rename your current project from MyFile.exe to MyFileInner.exe
2. Create new native application, call it MyFile.exe In new native application, check registry as per linked MS article. You will need different keys for .NET v4
3. If .net requirement not satisfied, your display your custom 'not installed' message(s), then exit
4. If .net requirement IS satisfied, start MyFileInner.exe

Comment: Bingo !!, I need a wrapper , but how ??

Comment: Updated my answer with the process involved

Comment: This seems to be my answer, but the problem is that we know have 2 .exe files!! is it possible to take them both in one, something like using managed code and unmanaged code together ?

Comment: It can be done but is a bit fiddly. This seems to be a pretty good example http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx